# differences between expected values

Tags: probability

assume a random variable $X$ taking only natural values (possibly also $0$). Assume two distributions $\pi$ and $\pi'$. Assume an arbitrary $0 < u < 1$.
Take these two inequalities:

1. $\sum_{n \in N} \pi(n) \cdot u^n \ge \sum_{n \in N} \pi'(n) \cdot u^n$
2. $\sum_{n \in N} \pi(n) \cdot n \ge \sum_{n \in N} \pi'(n) \cdot n$

The questions I'm trying to solve are the following:

- Does 1 imply 2?
- Does 2 imply 1?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The only valid implication is that 1. for every $u$ in $(0,1)$ (or for a sequence $(u_n)$ in $(0,1)$ such that $u_n\to1$) implies 2. **with the inequality reversed**.

Comment: Thanks. I see that the inequality has to be reversed, but how the implication can be proved? Thanks for your precious help!

Comment: @BertrandR did it, didn't he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least that can be said is the following :

$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \pi(n)u^n=g_\pi(u)$ is the generating function of $\pi$. Then your 1 is equivalent to $\forall u\in [0,1]$  :
$$g_\pi(u)\geq g_{\pi'}(u)$$

Your 2 is : $$g'_\pi(1)\geq g'_{\pi'}(1)$$

Edit :
$$\frac{g_\pi(u)-1}{u-1}\leq \frac{g_{\pi'}(u)-1}{u-1}$$
Then $u\rightarrow 1$ : $g'_\pi(1)\leq g'_{\pi'}(1)$

Comment: Thanks. If 1 holds for all $0 \le u \le 1$, can I infer 2?

Comment: See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

For a quick example, given any $X$, try  $X' = X+1$. We see that one statement is true while the other is false, so at least one of those directions doesn't work out no matter what. Ok, actually this can work for $X' = X-1$ too if $X \geq 1$. Is the question correct as stated?

Another example worth considering is to let $Y$ be a [fair] coin flip, and set $X' = Y(X+1) + (1-Y)(X-1)$  (if heads, $X' = X+1$, if tails, $X' = X-1$).

---

We can actually work with a fixed $u$ in certain situations:
Let $X,X'$ be arbitrary.

Assume (2) holds, so $E[X'] \leq E[X]$.

Now, let $\pi'_k(j)$ be the conditional distribution given $X=k$.
Further assume that $E[X' | X=k] \leq k$ (strong condition, implies (2)).

For (1), we then have by convexity of $f(x) = u^x$

$E[u^{X'}] = \sum_k \pi(k) \sum_j \pi'_k(j) u^{j} \geq \sum_k \pi(k) u^{E[X' | X=k]} \geq \sum_k \pi(k) u^k=E[u^X]$